# Does an application stand to gain speed by going from 3.5 to the latest version of the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a dozen different Winforms apps that are compiled for .NET 3.5.

In general, are there any speedups to be had (for instance, startup or anything else really) by targeting the latest version of the .NET framework (4.5.2 as of this date).

Are there any other benefits (e.g. RAM usage, etc...)?
P.S. I am not planning on rewriting the code.

Comment: This is really too broad of a question to be answered appropriately. Yes, there are performance differences between the two frameworks.  Whether or not you will benefit from these performance differences can only be known by knowing which framework features you are using;  The list of differences is documented and too numerous to address individually here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to answer precisely without know exactly what areas you are focusing on, but you may wish to review:

- [What's New in the .NET Framework 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171868(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx)

At the very least common denominator (again, not knowing what exactly you are doing) you will see performance gains in the garbage collector, which is common to all managed code in .NET.

From the above article on .NET 4.0, in the "Core New Features and Improvements" section (emphasis mine):

> #### Garbage Collection
>
> The .NET Framework 4 provides background garbage collection. This feature replaces concurrent garbage collection in previous versions **and provides better performance**. For more information, see Fundamentals of Garbage Collection.

Comment: Speaking in a little detail, there's even difference between GC in 4.0 and GC in 4.5 - see the article I found.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 4.5 includes a set of improvements to the GarbageCollector, so generally speaking, yes, your application can get a performance boost just from being run on 4.5 framework.

Here's an article from [MSDN Blogs about that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx) claiming for example:

> Before version 4, the .NET Framework provided a concurrent GC mode
>   that performed full GCs concurrently with user code (vs. blocking,
>   which pauses all user threads), thus reducing pause time for full GCs.
>   This mode was available only for workstation GC. In the .NET Framework
>   4, we delivered an improved version called the background workstation
>   garbage collection, which reduced latency but only benefited client
>   apps. In the .NET Framework 4.5, we have delivered background server
>   garbage collection, which is typically used for server apps. As a
>   result, all apps now have background GC available to them, regardless
>   of which GC they use.
>
> The new background server GC in the **.NET Framework 4.5 offloads much
>   of the GC work associated with a full blocking collection to dedicated
>   background GC threads that can run concurrently with user code,
>   resulting in much shorter (less noticeable) pauses. One customer
>   reported a 70% decrease in GC pause times.**

There were many more changes, some larger, some smaller, but that's the one I could readily recall. Just search for "What's new in .Net 4.5", there's little point in listing it all here.

However, nothing is guaranteeded. The fact that GC was improved and FooBar and BarBaz was improved doesn't necesarily have to have any impact on your application. It all depends on how your app is designed and what bottlenecks you are observing today on "old" framework. Purely theoretically speaking, you could even get a performance hit if your app is a very odd case, but I'd consider that to be very unlikely.